# Openshift REST API for getting token is not save it into oapi/v1/oauthaccesstokens

Tags: rest, oauth, openshift

I'm using next API for getting oauth token:
/oauth/authorize?client_id=openshift-challenging-client&response_type=token.

I get token, but it is not working then I do requests to some Openshift REST urls like /oapi/v1/nemespaces/namespace/routes.

The token work if I add it into oapi/v1/oauthaccesstokens by hands. 
How can I do this automatically ?

Version
OpenShift Master:v1.2.0
Kubernetes Master:v1.2.0-36-g4a3f9c5

Answer (score 0):

The token returned from the /oauth/authorize endpoint is created under /oapi/v1/oauthaccesstokens before being returned. Can you provide the request/response where you obtain the token, and where you attempt to use it against the API?